# Fail to join the variables with its name into a list using lapply?

Tags: r

I have tried to use the code below but failed. I want to know why it failed and what's the correct (and elegant) way to do that?

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
res <- lapply(ls(), function(x, l) { l$x <- get(x)}, l=list())
```

I hope I get the result like

```
res
# $a
# [1] 1

# $b
# [1] 2
```

but what I get is

```
res
# [[1]]
# [1] 1

# [[2]]
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mget` to obtain the value of more than one object and it returns a `named` `list`

```
mget(ls())
#$a
#[1] 1

#$b
#[1] 2
```

---

If we need to use `get`, then set the names with `ls()`

```
setNames(lapply(ls(), get), ls())
```

Comment: OMG that's awesome! But why my code fail and give this weird result? I dont know why [[1]] and [[2]] exist..

Comment: @VicaYang  Your code is only returning the object value if you check `lapply(ls(), function(x) get(x))`

Comment: yep.. I think it will return the return-value of my function, I will go to check the document for the details, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Using *sapply*:

```
sapply(ls(), get, simplify = FALSE)
# $a
# [1] 1
# 
# $b
# [1] 2
```

*sapply* has *simplify* and *USE.NAMES* arguments, both have default values of *TRUE*. So by setting *simplify* to *FALSE* we are keeping the result as named list.

Comment: @akrun correct, fixed, thank you. I have a bad habit.